# Rename a string in a row using the first word of the string in the row above it

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe of financial statements. The dataframe is in long format and I need to convert it to a wide dataframe to calculate new values. Some of the values, `Gross Margin before Incentives` and `Cash Incentives`, in the `item` column are duplicated but they all belong to groups represented by the first word in the string above their respective `Gross Margin before Incentives` values. This is an example of how my data looks like:

```
item                           balance
  <chr>                            <dbl>
1 Happy Sales                    538246.
2 Happy COGS                     691013.
3 Gross Margin before Incentives 732979.
4 Cash Incentives                795271.
5 Sad Sales                      777362.
6 Sad COGS                       641143.
```

I need to rename the `Gross Margin before Incentives` and `Cash Incentives` values in the `item` column with the first word in the value directly above `Gross Margin before Incentives`. For example, row 3 and row 4 in `item`, `Gross Margin before Incentives` and `Cash Incentives`, should be `Happy Gross Margin before Incentives` and `Happy Cash Incentives`. There are instances where `Cash Incentives` isn't observed in a group.

How can I rename instances of `Gross Margin before Incentives` and `Cash Incentives` when it does occur? I began by subsetting the data to only include the values in `item` that I need to fix.

my code so far:

```
# subset the data 

strings_to_clean <- c("Sales", "COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives", "Cash Incentives")
subset_data <- subset(example, grepl(paste(strings_to_clean, collapse="|"), item))
```

data:

```
structure(list(item = c("Happy Sales", "Happy COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives", 
"Cash Incentives", "Sad Sales", "Sad COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives", 
"Cash Incentives", "Moody Sales", "Moody COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives", 
"Cash Incentives", "Quiet Sales", "Quiet COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives", 
"Loud Sales", "Loud COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives"), 
    balance = c(538245.742201671, 691013.302590931, 732979.295329896, 
    795270.513380734, 777362.375851466, 641142.897993899, 631125.453588359, 
    719267.992685639, 691097.434737858, 787648.5870127, 773735.724156151, 
    839982.810591622, 594245.171673631, 817496.544758698, 696496.677601699, 
    640577.505041572, 715166.623728619, 646765.952258766)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Do you have a full list of the potential prefixes (happy, sad, moody, quiet etc). or do you need to infer those from the column somehow? Alternatively, are gross margin before Incentives and Cash incentives the only values that might be missing a prefix?

Comment: I need to infer them from the column. Gross margin before Incentives and Cash incentives are the only duplicates I found.

Comment: Ok, but are the 4 `strings_to_clean` the only things that might appear after the prefix? i.e. if a value starts with one of those four, we know it is missing a prefix (and vice versa?)

Comment: Yes, that's what I believe. Sales was split into its components but gross margin and cash incentives wasn't labeled with the group prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach. You can:

1. Get the first word of each item
2. Use the list of `strings_to_clean` to decide whether the first word is a prefix or not
3. Use `fill` to add in the previous prefix for those rows with missing prefixes
4. Concatenate the new prefixes onto the original items.

I left the helper columns in and was verbose for clarity, but some of these steps could easily be condensed for concision.

```r
library(tidyverse)

subset_data <- structure(list(item = c("Happy Sales", "Happy COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives", "Cash Incentives", "Sad Sales", "Sad COGS", "Gross Margin beforeIncentives", "Cash Incentives", "Moody Sales", "Moody COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives", "Cash Incentives", "Quiet Sales", "Quiet COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives", "Loud Sales", "Loud COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives"), balance = c(538245.742201671, 691013.302590931, 732979.295329896, 795270.513380734, 777362.375851466, 641142.897993899, 631125.453588359, 719267.992685639, 691097.434737858, 787648.5870127, 773735.724156151, 839982.810591622, 594245.171673631, 817496.544758698, 696496.677601699, 640577.505041572, 715166.623728619, 646765.952258766)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

subset_data %>%
  mutate(
    first_word = str_extract(item, "^.*? "),
    has_prefix = !first_word %in% c("Sales ", "COGS ", "Gross ", "Cash "),
    prefix = if_else(has_prefix, first_word, NA_character_)
  ) %>%
  fill(prefix) %>%
  mutate(
    prefix_to_add = if_else(has_prefix, "", prefix),
    item = str_c(prefix_to_add, item)
  )
#> # A tibble: 18 x 6
#>    item                      balance first_word has_prefix prefix  prefix_to_add
#>    <chr>                       <dbl> <chr>      <lgl>      <chr>   <chr>        
#>  1 Happy Sales               538246. "Happy "   TRUE       "Happy… ""           
#>  2 Happy COGS                691013. "Happy "   TRUE       "Happy… ""           
#>  3 Happy Gross Margin befor… 732979. "Gross "   FALSE      "Happy… "Happy "     
#>  4 Happy Cash Incentives     795271. "Cash "    FALSE      "Happy… "Happy "     
#>  5 Sad Sales                 777362. "Sad "     TRUE       "Sad "  ""           
#>  6 Sad COGS                  641143. "Sad "     TRUE       "Sad "  ""           
#>  7 Sad Gross Margin beforeI… 631125. "Gross "   FALSE      "Sad "  "Sad "       
#>  8 Sad Cash Incentives       719268. "Cash "    FALSE      "Sad "  "Sad "       
#>  9 Moody Sales               691097. "Moody "   TRUE       "Moody… ""           
#> 10 Moody COGS                787649. "Moody "   TRUE       "Moody… ""           
#> 11 Moody Gross Margin befor… 773736. "Gross "   FALSE      "Moody… "Moody "     
#> 12 Moody Cash Incentives     839983. "Cash "    FALSE      "Moody… "Moody "     
#> 13 Quiet Sales               594245. "Quiet "   TRUE       "Quiet… ""           
#> 14 Quiet COGS                817497. "Quiet "   TRUE       "Quiet… ""           
#> 15 Quiet Gross Margin befor… 696497. "Gross "   FALSE      "Quiet… "Quiet "     
#> 16 Loud Sales                640578. "Loud "    TRUE       "Loud " ""           
#> 17 Loud COGS                 715167. "Loud "    TRUE       "Loud " ""           
#> 18 Loud Gross Margin before… 646766. "Gross "   FALSE      "Loud " "Loud "
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` package you can do this, by exploiting the regular structure of data

```
library(dplyr)
# define vector of strings to use 
strings_to_clean <- 
    c("Sales", "COGS", "Gross Margin before Incentives", "Cash Incentives")
# code
df %>% 
    mutate(item = 
               ifelse(grepl(paste0(strings_to_clean[3:4], collapse = "|"), item), 
                      paste(gsub(paste0(c(strings_to_clean, "\\s+$"), collapse = "|"), "", lag(item, 2)), item), 
                      item))
```

This is basically saying

(1) if `item` has either 'Gross Margin before Incentives' or 'Cash Incentives'

(2) concatenate to `item` the firm name from two rows up (`lag(item, 2)`) : you find the firm name by taking `lag(item, 2)` and removing all strings from `strings_to_clean`